# Помогите разобраться с кнопками Kivy

Tags: python, button, kivy

Нужно сделать кнопку, при нажатии на которую телефон завибрирует. Вроде просто, но код ниже не работет, поднимается NotImplementedError, если в функцию вствить обычный print(), то все работает. Объясните, пожлуйста, в чем проблема.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from plyer import vibrator


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        # use a (r, g, b, a) tuple
        blue = (0, 0, 1.5, 2.5)
        red = (2.5, 0, 0, 1.5)
        btn =  Button(text='Touch me!', background_color=blue, font_size=120)
        btn.bind(on_press=self.callback)
        self.label = Label(text="------------", font_size='50sp')
        layout.add_widget(btn)
        layout.add_widget(self.label)
        return layout

    def callback(self, event):
        vibrator.vibrate(100)

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Насколько я помню нужно добавить в конструктор кнопки аргумент on_press, отвечающий за вызов функции, выполняющейся при соответствующем действии. Измените строчку определения кнопки (btn) на следующее: btn =  Button(text='Touch me!', background_color=blue, font_size=120, on_press=self.callback)